# "Interdum sane, qui cogitare se dicit nondum constitutum sibi certi quidquam fatetur"

Tags: sentence-translation

In the Thesaurus of Iohannes Matthias Gesnerus under [cogito](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=KIVNAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA989&lpg=PA989&dq=Inter+cogitare+et+deliberare&source=bl&ots=Yzavx6ob5o&sig=ACfU3U0SjFkgom1kq80kVVgoraMWVzNeLg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSkI-X-ePqAhWRjqQKHQCVD08Q6AEwAHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=Inter%20cogitare%20et%20deliberare&f=false): (clearer [link](http://mateo.uni-mannheim.de/camenaref/gesner/gesner1/v1/jpg/s0989.html))

> inter cogitare et deliberare hoc interest, *cogitare* est dubitare, *deliberare*, confirmare. Haec Nonius 5,28. **Interdum sane, qui *cogitare* se dicit nondum constitutum sibi certi quidquam
> fatetur.** Sed non est perpetua haec differentia. Nam *deliberare* saepe dicitur qui consilium petit, et *cogitat* de profectione qui proficisci iam ante constituit.

I have it all except the sentence in bold, which I can't make grammatical. Not sure on so many things (ceteri: adj or gen. of Noun; indirect speech or not - where does it start if so?), but every combination I tried failed to make sense.

(Frustra de hac sentenia *cogitabam*, nunc igitur *delibero* et peto auxilium vestrum. Gratias vobis)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I would translate the bolded phrase:

> Sometimes, of course, he who says that he is thinking [*cogitare*] is claiming that nothing certain has been decided by him yet.

Here's a breakdown:

**qui cogitare se dicit...**

This is the subject: "He who says that he is thinking"

**fatetur**

This is the verb: "is claiming"

**nondum constitutum sibi**

This is a dative of agent (thanks to TKR for the correction), meaning "not yet decided by him."

**certi quidquam**

The *certi* is an example of a [partitive genitive](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/genitive), e.g. "quid novi" = "something new." In this case, "quidquam certi" means "something certain." There is an understood "esse" that links this to the previous: "nothing certain has been decided by him yet."

Comment: I'd take *sibi* as dative of agent -- "nothing certain has yet been decided by him" (taking the implied *esse* with *constitutum*).

Comment: Thanks! this missing *esse* made it harder for me. How frequent an "implied esse" in indirect speech is used?

Comment: @TKR I think you're right! Edited accordingly

Comment: @d_e I find that *esse* is rarely made explicit in indirect speech.

Comment: @TKR  Descriptively speaking, I agree that here _sibi_ is a "dative of agent". However, to the extent that datives of agent can be theoretically reduced to datives of possession (cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12844/can-a-dative-of-agent-appear-in-an-ablative-absolute-construction ), I'd eliminate the correction over "possession". Incidentally, note that the presence of a dative of agent here is a nice evidence for the existence of an elliptical _esse_. Importantly, as claimed in my link, datives of agent, unlike ablatives of agent, cannot **directly** depend on a participle.

Comment: @Mitomino I agree that the distinction is a fuzzy one. As often in such cases, it's not clear to me whether there's any Latin-internal justification for positing two distinct readings or whether the apparent ambiguity is an artifact of translation. I wonder if there are any extant discussions by ancient grammarians of such apparently ambiguous constructions.

Comment: @TKR translations often conflate {datives/ablatives} of agent (typically via a _by_-phrase), whereby the relevant morphosyntactically-encoded semantic distinction in Latin is lost. If you take a look at this link (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255723772_Le_datif_d'agent_'datiuus_auctoris'_un_fantome_dans_la_syntaxe_latine ), you'll see that the "dative of agent" is more similar to a dativus iudicantis (in my view, it is even more similar to a dative of possession) than to an "ablative of agent". I agree it'd be nice to see if ancient grammarians said anything about this

Answer (score 2):

What follows is not an answer but just contains some (grammatically relevant) remarks on the translation given above by brianpck. I've decided to include these remarks here as an answer since I'm afraid I've already posted too many comments in brianpck's post...

Let's start with the following fragment:

> *nondum constitutum sibi*
> "This is a dative of agent (thanks to TKR for the correction), meaning 'not yet decided by him.'"

This translation could set some learners of Latin like *d_e* wondering: "fine, but then is there **any** semantic difference between a "dative of agent" (*sibi*) and an "ablative of agent" (*a se*)? Should both be translated as "by him"?

When dealing with the difference between "datives of agent" and "ablatives of agent", some (good) grammars of Latin often include relevant pairs like the following one:

> ***Mihi** consilium captum diu est* (Cic. *Fam.* 5.19) 'lit. 'For me there is a decision taken for long time' (NB I: the participle *captum* is NOT part of the verb(al form) but is rather acting as an adjectival predicative of the nominative subject *consilium*; NB II: for reasons clarified below, the existential "For me there is..." is better rendered in many languages via a possesive verb: "I have + Direct Object + predicative of DO").

> ***A me** consilium captum est* 'The decision {has been/was taken} by me' (NB: the participle *captum* is part of the complex verbal form).

Cf. the following relevant remark made by the French latinist Lavency (1985: 165), which, I hope, is quite transparent for English speakers (otherwise, please let me know): "on notera la différence entre ***Mihi*** (Dat.) *consilium captum est* (présent correspondant à: *Mihi consilium captum fuit*) et ***A me*** (*ab* + Abl.) *consilium captum est* (passé correspondant à: *A me consilium capitur*)". Importantly, note that the participle *captum* is **adjectival** in the former example with *mihi*, whereas it is **verbal** in the latter with *a me* (for further discussion on the important distinction between "adjectival passives" and "verbal passives", see this [link](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8815/on-the-typical-ambiguity-of-porta-clausa-est)).

As I've pointed out in some comments on brianpck's answer, the notion of **possession** is relevant when dealing with so-called "datives of agent". For example, authors of excellent descriptive grammars of Latin like [Lavency (1985: 165-166)](https://books.google.es/books/about/Usus.html?id=R3hrQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) have noted parallelisms like the one between *Caesari equitatus coactus erat* and *Caesar equitatum coactum habebat* (Caes. *BG* 1.15). Indeed, there is a close relationship between so-called "datives of agent" and "datives of possession". So, for the purposes of the present post, note that a parallelism can also be put forward between the following  constructions. The former involves a dative of agent *sibi* (which is in fact a dative of possession!), whereas the latter involves the possessive verb *habere*:

> *nondum **constitutum (esse) sibi** certi quidquam*

> *nondum **constitutum habere** se certi quidquam*

To recapitulate, consider the full translation given by brianpck:

> Sometimes, of course, he who says that he is thinking [cogitare] is claiming that nothing certain has been decided by him yet.

Note that this *trans*lation has *trans*formed:

(i) a Latin adjectival passive INTO an English verbal passive (please note that in Classical Latin the adjectival participle *constitutum*, when coappearing, for example, with a "dative of agent", does NOT form a perfect infinitive with *esse*);

(ii) a Latin dative of agent (a dative of possession; see above) INTO an English *by*-phrase (the latter being more similar to the Latin "ablative of agent").

In short, note that brianpck's translation is rather a translation of *nondum constitutum **a se** (certi quidquam)*, where *constitutum* does form a perfect infinitive with an elliptical *esse*.

Please don't get me wrong! I'm NOT saying that there are some "mistakes" in brianpck's translation. The aim of the present "answer" is just to exemplify how some subtle grammatical facts of the original text *can* change when *trans*lating them to another language. As is well-known, translations often involve, i.a., a non-trivial process of (natural) adaptation of the original information to the target language, whereby some subtle nuances in the original text *can* be lost. To rephrase/reuse an [admittedly polemical title](http://ling.umd.edu/%7Ejlidz/Teaching/SP06Seminar/newmeyer2003.pdf) (I know some of you strongly disagree with Newmeyer's statement!), "translation is translation and grammar is grammar".

Take-home message:
As a Spanish colleague of mine (Ignacio Bosque, a famous grammarian of this language) likes to say, "en la lengua —y en particular en la Gramática— todo son matices" ('in language -and in particular in Grammar- everything is a matter of nuances').

FURTHER READING:

- For related discussion on the different grammatical behavior (e.g., the different syntactic distribution) of "datives of agent" and "ablatives of agent", see this [link](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/12844/can-a-dative-of-agent-appear-in-an-ablative-absolute-construction).
- Take a look at this excellent descriptive [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255723772_Le_datif_d%27agent_%27datiuus_auctoris%27_un_fantome_dans_la_syntaxe_latine) on *datives of agent* (NB: it is not technical at all but is written in French).

Comment: Romance languages like Catalan (my native language) can account for the minimal contrast _**Mihi** hoc est constitutum_ and _**A me** hoc est constitutum_ as follows: '(Jo) tinc això decidit' (lit. 'I have this decided') and 'Això {ha estat/va ser} decidit per mi" (lit. This {has been/was} decided by me'), respectively.

Comment: A couple of ways come to mind in which the classification of the OP's sentence as a dative of possession might be tested. 1 The sentence has an omitted copula; are copulas ever omitted in the possessive dative construction? I don't think I've ever seen that; if it's rare or unattested, that would be a problem for this analysis. 2 Taking the omitted *est* as a present-tense copula rather than part of a periphrastic perfect with the participle implies that this construction should never trigger secondary sequence; that too is in principle falsifiable, though it may be hard to find relevant data.

Comment: (2 cont) And more generally, temporal expressions with past semantics should not be licensed: Heri constitutum est a me / *mihi...

Comment: @TKR Many thanks for your comments! Let me start with your last comment. _Heri constitutum est mihi_ is of course expected to be possible on the reading of _mihi_ as a beneficiary dative. This (irrelevant) reading aside, your contrast _Heri constitutum est a me / *mihi..._, gives strong evidence for Lavency’s/my claim that _constitutum est_ cannot be understood as a complex verbal form (e.g. “was decided”) when a "dative of agent" is present. In contrast, note that brianpck seems to take it for granted that _constitutum est_ can form a complex verbal form even if a dative of agent is present.

Comment: @TKR Recall the very important fact that datives of agent, **unlike** ablatives of agent, cannot depend **directly** on a participle/-nd- predicate (please see 1st "further reading" above). Accordingly, the (explicit or implicit) presence of a verbal form (typically, _esse_) is compulsory for a dative of agent (i.e., a dative of possession!) to be licensed. Since datives of agent (e.g., unlike beneficiary datives; again **please** see the 1st further reading) cannot depend directly on a participle/_-nd-_ predicate, elliptical cases of the copula are expected to be exceptional.

Comment: However, it is true that elliptical instances of the copula can be found, typically in the subordinate clause domain: e.g., _Caesar maturandum sibi existimavit_ (Caes. _Gal._ 1.37.4). Still, note that there is strong evidence for the “possessive” parallelism between _Mihi currendum  est_ and _Mihi est liber_: e.g., cf. _Habeo  currendum_ and _Habeo librum_. Why the copula is obligatory in “purely” nominal possessive dative constructions but can be elliptical in proper dative of agent constructions (especially in subordiante contexts: see Caesar’s example above) can be related...(next comment!)

Comment: (can be related)... to the morphosemantics of the -nd- (_maturandum_) or –t- participial (_constitutum_) predicate, which is missing in the former. However, this difference should not lead us to consider that the syntatic and semantic status of _mihi_ is different (say, possessive and agentive) in both constructions.

Comment: To clarify, my "Heri constitutum est a me / *mihi..." was not meant as a description of actual usage, but as a prediction made by the analysis you cite -- I have no idea whether or not it's borne out by the usage facts.

Comment: @TKR, Right, right! The contrast _Heri constitutum est a me / *mihi..._ (on the relevant reading of _mihi_; see above) is just {Lavency's/my} prediction (not yours!).

Comment: I do think the differing behavior of the copula is grounds for treating this as different from the possessive dative construction, though. In that construction the reason *esse* can't be elided is presumably that it's existential. If it's the case that the possessive dative construction involves existential *esse*, and that existential *esse* is never elided (both of which I think are true), then the OP's sentence must be something other than a possessive dative construction.

Comment: You point out that "possessive dative construction involves existential esse". Do you really think that, for example, _Nunc est (nobis) bibendum_ is not "existential"? In any case, please note the following important parallelism: cf. _Mihi currendum est_ and _Mihi est liber_ & _Habeo currendum_ and _Habeo librum_, which points towards the very same status of both copulas and datives. For further discussion, please see https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11169/null-expletive-objects-in-latin-cariotae-cum-ficis-certandum-habent-plin-ep

Comment: I'm not sure how to decide whether the *esse* of *Nunc est (nobis) bibendum* is existential -- if it's never elided, that would be good evidence, but I don't know if that's the case. The parallelism you note is indeed suggestive. But the copula ellipsis difference still argues against the dative of possession analysis in my mind.

Comment: @TKR For example, in Spanish we use the very same "existential" verb _haber_ 'lit. to have (but it means 'There+be') in both _nunc est bibendum_ and in the elliptical context above of _Caesar maturandum [esse] sibi existimavit_: cf. Sp. "Ahora _**hay**_ que beber"  (cf. "hay"--"habet-ibi") and Sp. "César creyó que **había** que darse prisa" (cf. "había"--"habebat").  Unsurprisingly, the typical English **existential** construction "there is..." is translated into Spanish by the existential verb "hay...". E.g., take a look at https://www.thoughtco.com/spanish-verb-haber-3078306

Comment: Existential to obligation is a common semantic shift, certainly -- cf. Eng. *have to*, for that matter.

Comment: Cf. also the parallelism between Sp. _No **hay** nada que hacer_ (HAVE) and It. _Non c'**è** niente da fare_ (BE), lit. 'There is nothing to do'.

Comment: That existentials can diachronically acquire obligational sense doesn't mean that they're the same thing synchronically. As I see it: the dative of possession, as that term is normally used, definitionally depends on an existential *esse*; existential *esse* definitionally cannot be elided; therefore, despite semantic commonalities, the dative of agent (for which this is not true) cannot be reduced to a dative of possession. (Of course, if it turns out *esse* can be elided in the possessive dative construction, my argument fails; I've just posted a question on that topic.)

Comment: @TKR *Dicit sibi sororem* is ungrammatical. Well, in my opinion, {Lavency's/my} argument does not fail for this obvious fact. I think that the obvious ungrammaticality of that example should not lead us to consider that the dative *mihi* in *mihi est liber* and *nunc est mihi dormiendum* is different. It's the same (e.g., unlike the beneficiary dative, which is different from them. For example, unlike the dative of agency/of possession, the beneficiary one can directly depend on participles).

Comment: One can continue to "label/classify" the dative *mihi* of *mihi est liber* as "possessive dative" and that of *mihi currendum* est as "dative of agent" but it is the SAME dative, realized in different domains (lexical and functional ones, respectively). E.g., cf. the distinction between lexical/functional categories as established by generative linguists. In any case, thanks, TKR, for your time and for your comments! A pleasure, as always!